# Climbing and finger strength training with extensor injury

Tags: injury, rock-climbing, fingers

I think the extensor tendons of the fingers are under little strain while climbing. (I can move mine with the other hand while pulling 20+ kg in a half crimp position.) Does it still make sense to take a break from training when one has a slight extensor injury from an unrelated cut – slight enough that it doesn’t interfere with the hand mobility and didn’t cause problems during some, perhaps ill-considered, training sessions? If so, how long should such a break be?

Comment: Please don't seek advice on the internet on what is and isn't safe with an existing injury. There's no way for us to know enough details about the injury to make safe guidelines.